# Is it necessary to have content-type headers for content much like request headers in a PUT/POST request to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to web api and writing a code where by I'm sending in json data for a PUT/POST request to web api (web service).
I'm doing the following

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var gizmo = some json data;
    HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"url");
    req.Content = new StringContent(some json data, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500);
    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
}
```

My question is **do I essentially have to put the code for content-type for content header** or not and I have observed that even if do include content-type as "applicatipn/json" exclusively for content-type in my code 
and check my request in Fiddler, it still shows content-type :text/html. **Why is that?** .
All your replies will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do put code for content-type. The bit you don't have to include with JSON is the accepts, although I personally feel it is better to include accepts, as it explicitly states intent, but your mileage may vary.

Here is a blog post I just found that explains some of the issues around not doing this:
http://truncatedcodr.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/asp-net-web-api-always-set-content-type/

EDIT:

See comments. Apparently, you do not have to specify content type any more. Regardless, explicit coding is preferred to implicit coding, at least in most Enterprise software. The reason is simple: When you use implicit coding, the intent of the code is often lost. Note that I am not saying "don't use abstractions that are available", as there is nothing wrong with allowing Microsoft (or an open source development team) to take over the plumbing of your application and use the abstractions they provide to simplify and reduce your code. If you rely on defaults, rather than set the values, you create some future risk, and this should be considered. In some cases, it is worth the risk. The tendency, today, is to use implicit coding as much as possible, as it saves keystrokes. As a consultant, I can attest this is very often the core of future problems.

Comment: Actually I did see this article while searching for an answer to my question, the thing is if go down to bottom of this article where people have posted their comments, originally the article was written in September 2012 and then one of the guys in his comments(which was written in December 2013) said that its not necessary to give content-type in your code anymore, may because of the advancement in web api over the period of  1 year .i.e from 09/2102 till 12/2013.

Comment: @user2913184 - That is good to know. IN general, I am still fond of explicit coding, as it leads to fewer surprises.

Comment: I have updated my code above,so after including content-type exclusively I'm still getting the same old error and "response" object says error code 405 method not allowed.

Comment: @user2913184 - Have you examined the request and response in Fiddler? I do this with REST endpoints, as you have so little feedback otherwise. Run the query and then walk through the request to make sure it is not missing something. I would also examine the other side (the service) to make sure there is no configuration element set incorrectly. When I am beating my head against a wall, I often find an example that works and then tailor it to my code. Post mortem, I compare the working code to what I original did, so I can understand what went wrong.

Comment: And the second surprise that I get is that when I analyze my call to web api.Fiddler says it's a PUT request though I'm exclusively defining HttpMethod.Post in my code above.

Comment: I don't see the request (req) wired in anywhere, but the PostAsJsonAsync() should still do a post. If it were me, at this point, I would spike off something from a site like (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) and see if I can solve the problem. Then compare the code. I find I generally miss one little thing. If I had time right now, I would play with it myself, as the code appears fine.

Comment: got it i changed the above code from putjsonasync to postjsonasync and im getting a status code of 200, which means its successful and the a new row is present in the database but one of the columns that takes value from json data is still empty, when all the other fields are taking their values from json data why is there a column with null value.

Comment: can u guide me a bit as to how to wire the req, I'm not getting u on this wiring thing.

Comment: I looked at the article at asp.net/web-api but it doesn't talk about content-type and how to wire it.